# Webpage button on-click image update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if it's possible to have an HTML form with a text field and a button, wherein you enter a string (say 5) and on pressing the button, the image "image5.jpg", stored on the server, is rendered on the webpage.

I believe it boils down to coding a button "on-click method":

1. Read a text field and form a filename string for the image
2. Updating the image, preferably (OR redirecting the user to "http://.../image5.jpg" would do as well)

I'm not terribly familiar with much more than basic HTML, but I can hack it together if I know what will get the job done.
Thanks.

Comment: You are correct! (1) `textField.value` and (2) `img.src = value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// DOM ready handler
$(function(){

  // Click on change image button handler
  $('#select').click(function(){

    // Get the value entered in the number input
    var image = $('#number').val();

    // Change the source of the image
    $('#image').attr('src', "http://somewebsite.com/image" + image +".jpg");
  });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/0rn00L4a/

There are no real images to show, but if you inspect the DOM you will see it changes the image to things like

```
<img id="image" src="http://somewebsite.com/image2.jpg">
```

So if you put in your correct image path, it will just show them immediately when you press the button.

*You could just do it on the `change` event of the input, but that is a little jarring.*

Comment: Last thing: How do the HTML and Javascript go together? Put the JS in <script> tags within the body?

Comment: Yes. As the code is in a DOM ready handler and will not run until the page is loaded, the script can go anywhere in the page. Head, end of body etc